# Slackbot not able to pick up messages

Tags: api, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to create a simple slackbot and I can get the thing to run on start and almost anything else, but it will not pick up incoming messages from any channel. It's not generating any errors what so ever which makes it very frusterating.

things I've tried so far:

1. adding the bot to the channel
2. console logging inside the message block
3. adding a catch

No matter what I do the bot seems to just outright ignore the prompt "on.message". I don't get it. My code is below.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { WebClient } = require("@slack/web-api");
const { createEventAdapter } = require("@slack/events-api");
const slackEvents = createEventAdapter(process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET);
const { RTMClient } = require("@slack/rtm-api");
const axios = require('axios')
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const pool = require("./pool");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("build"));

let config = {
  headers: {
    "X-Auth-Client": process.env.BG_AUTH_CLIENT,
    "X-Auth-Token": process.env.BG_AUTH_TOKEN,
  },
};
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("server running on: ", PORT);
  });
const token = process.env.SLACK_TOKEN;

const web = new WebClient(token);

const conversationId = "C0139RJPUEM";

// The client is initialized and then started to get an active connection to the platform
const rtm = new RTMClient(token);



slackEvents.on('error', console.error);

slackEvents.start().then(() => {
    (async () => {
      const res = await web.chat.postMessage({
        icon_emoji: ":email:",
        channel: conversationId,
        text: "Testing connection",
      });

    message
      console.log("Message sent: ", res.ts);
    })();
    console.log("bot listening on port", PORT);
});

    slackEvents.on("message", (event) => {
      console.log(
        `Received a message event: user ${event.user} in channel ${event.channel} says ${event.text}`
      );
      (async () => {
        // See: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage
        const res = await web.chat.postMessage({
          icon_emoji: ":email:",
          channel: conversationId,
          text: "Testing message",
        });

        // `res` contains information about the posted message
        console.log("Message sent: ", res.ts);
      })();
      // }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, I was using a library that was not compatible, plus I didn't set up API event subscriptions and a few other dumb things. Oh well. Hopefully this will help someone who might casually come across this.